# $S=\left\{ x\in \mathbb{R} ^n:x^{\mathsf{T}}Ax+b^{\mathsf{T}}x+c\le 0 \right\} $, and $T=\left\{ x\in \mathbb{R} ^n:g^{\mathsf{T}}x+h=0 \right\} $.

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization

Let set $S=\left\{ x\in \mathbb{R} ^n:x^{\mathsf{T}}Ax+b^{\mathsf{T}}x+c\le 0 \right\} $, and $T=\left\{ x\in \mathbb{R} ^n:g^{\mathsf{T}}x+h=0 \right\} $.

(1) if $A$ is positive semi-definite matrix, prove the set $S$ is convex.

(2) if $A+gg^{\mathsf{T}}$ is  positive semi-definite matrix, prove the set $S\bigcap{T}$ is convex.

What I know is that if $\forall x^{(1)},x^{(2)} \in S$ and $\forall \lambda\in\left[0,1\right]$, we all have $\lambda x^{(1)}+(1-\lambda)x^{(2)} \in S$, then the set $S$ is named as convex set, however, I cannot employ this convex set definition to prove the above conclusion.

Comment: Zeta, please, write what you have tried. Click [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and read carefully it, then try to improve your question.

Comment: Zeta, I will help you solve your exercise if you do what [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) recommends.

Comment: Perhaps @Angelo would be kind enough to emphasize the conditions in the link they deem sufficient to provide said help to the OP. 

To the OP: you know and acknowledge the condition of convexity, yet your attempts of applying it to $S$, and where exactly you struggle, have not been demonstrated, despite your claim of not being able to.

Comment: Zeta, you should provide more context. A question can sometimes be answered in one sentence when the discussion is between two experts familiar with each other's background, while the same question may take many paragraphs of detailed computation when being shown to an undergraduate student. By providing a context you help the potential responders to your question give you the best help you need. **Click [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) in order to learn some different ways you can add context to your question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\;S=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:x^{\mathsf{T}}Ax+b^{\mathsf{T}}x+c\leqslant0\right\}\;.$

Now, we will suppose that $\,A\,$ is a positive semi-definite matrix and prove the set $\,S\,$ is convex.

$\forall\,x_1,x_2\in S\;$ and $\;\forall\lambda\in\left[0,1\right]\;$, it results that

$\lambda\left(x_1^{\mathsf{T}}Ax_1+b^{\mathsf{T}}x_1+c\right)+(1-\lambda)\left(x_2^{\mathsf{T}}Ax_2+b^{\mathsf{T}}x_2+c\right)\leqslant0\;\;,$

$\lambda x_1^{\mathsf{T}}\!Ax_1+(1\!-\!\lambda)x_2^{\mathsf{T}}\!Ax_2 +b^{\mathsf{T}}\big[\lambda x_1+(1\!-\!\lambda)x_2\big]+c\leqslant0\,.\;\;\color{blue}{(1)}$

Since $\,A\,$ is a positive semi-definite matrix, it follows that

$-\lambda(1-\lambda)(x_1-x_2)^{\mathsf{T}}A(x_1-x_2)\leqslant0\;\;,$

$\left(\lambda^2\!-\!\lambda\right)\! x_1^{\mathsf{T}}\!Ax_1\!+\!\lambda(1\!-\!\lambda)\!\left(x_1^{\mathsf{T}}\!Ax_2\!+\!x_2^{\mathsf{T}}\!Ax_1\!-\!x_2^{\mathsf{T}}\!Ax_2\right)\!\leqslant0\,.\;\;\color{blue}{(2)}$

By adding $(1)$ and $(2)$, side-by-side, we get that

$\lambda x_1^{\mathsf{T}}\!A\lambda x_1\!+\!\lambda x_1^{\mathsf{T}}\!A(1\!-\!\lambda)x_2\!+\!(1\!-\!\lambda)x_2^{\mathsf{T}}\!A\lambda x_1\!+\!(1\!-\!\lambda)x_2^{\mathsf{T}}\!A(1\!-\!\lambda)x_2+b^{\mathsf{T}}\big[\lambda x_1\!+\!(1\!-\!\lambda)x_2\big]+c\leqslant0\;\;,$

$\lambda x_1^{\mathsf{T}}A\big[\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2\big]+(1-\lambda)x_2^{\mathsf{T}}A\big[\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2\big]+b^{\mathsf{T}}\big[\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2\big]+c\leqslant0\;\;,$

$\big[\lambda x_1\!+\!(1\!-\!\lambda)x_2\big]^{\!\mathsf{T}}\!\!A\big[\lambda x_1\!+\!(1\!-\!\lambda)x_2\big]\!\!+\!b^{\mathsf{T}}\big[\lambda x_1\!+\!(1\!-\!\lambda)x_2\big]\!\!+\!c\leqslant0$

consequently ,

$\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2 \in S\;.$

In this way, we have proved the set $\,S\,$ is convex.